# Bagging Classifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn

In a two class classification problem, is there any method to select the number of positive and negative training instances to be chosen while using the standard bagging classifier in Python ?

`logreg = BaggingClassifier(linear_model.LogisticRegression(C=1e3),max_samples=1, max_features=1);`

Sometimes the Bagging algorithm chooses only positive samples and the code gives a run-time error.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source code (https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/51a765a/sklearn/ensemble/bagging.py#L361) there is no way to do it.

But I've noticed that you are using 1 (an integer value) as max_samples and max_features. Using this value you are saying that the Bagging should use just one FEATURE per estimator. If you want it to use ALL features you have to use 1.0.

Maybe this is what is causing you trouble.